# Not able to access the port 3000 cloudfront ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-route53

I am able to access the port 3000 via Public IPv4 DNS. But i am unable to access the port via cloudfront distribution.

1. i have added the 3000 port in Security group inbound rule.

Cloudfront distribution details

- Viewer protocol policy : Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
- Cache key and origin requests :  Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)
- ProtocolInfo : HTTP Only

Comment: What do you mean by "i am unable to access the port via cloudfront distribution"? What are you doing? Are you trying to access port 3000 on a CloudFront URL? That won't work -- CloudFront serves on port 80 and 443. Can you please tell us more about what you are wanting to do?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes! i am trying to access port 3000 on a CloudFront URL.

Comment: This is not possible. CloudFront only serves content on port 80 and 443. You should configure your **origin** to be port 3000, but when accessing CloudFront _do not_ specify a port. This will make CloudFront access your origin's port 3000 but CloudFront will serve content as normal on port 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS).